# How to run queries with psql URI

Tags: postgresql, heroku, uri, heroku-postgres

I typed psql URI (the URI being the URI from heroku credentials) into the command line. But when I try to write queries (i.e. CREATE TABLE example (column1 VARCHAR(100), column2 VARCHAR(200));) it doesn't do anything. No error message, just gives me a new line. 
Typing "\d" just says no relations found. How can I make queries?

Comment: did you end your command with a `;`?

Comment: ya, still didn't work. I ended up just giving up and going through admin4 instead.